# Bootstrap - I reset the form, but input errors are still shown?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, reset

I have the following form.

```
<form id='form'>
<input type='email' id='email' />
etc. etc.
</form>
```

So if I type 'hello' into the email field and press submit, I get an error and it stops the submit from happening. The input field then has a red border. Also, I override the submit so that it submits it using AJAX.

If I want to reset the form (using JS), I call:

```
 $('#form')[0].reset();
```

This resets the form, but leaves the red border.

I try inspecting the element of the input field but it doesn't show any additional classes, but it has a red border? Is this a phantom class or something.